# Kotlin multiplatform projects run JVM module test in IDEA

Tags: unit-testing, intellij-idea, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm using kotlin multiplatform project with following source set:

- commonMain
- commonTest
- iosArm64Main
- jvmMain
- jvmTest

I want to run unit test in jvmTest under Idea using "green arrow". Runnings test Idea do not copy test resources folder under jvmTest to build folder. If I use Idea settings "Delegate IDE build/run action to Gradle" and Run Test Using "Gradle Test Runner", resources are copied under processedResources. But Idea still don't see them and tests fails.

When I use Gradle build test run fine.

Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue tracked as [KT-24463](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-24463): the Kotlin IntelliJ plugin does not correctly add the resources to the classpath in Kotlin Multiplatform projects when using IntelliJ runners.

Please follow that ticket to get the updates.

Until it is fixed, you can run the tests with the Gradle test runner as a workaround.